# Serial code much slower than using only one thread in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing

So, I was doing some benchmark tests with threads, and i wrote these pieces of code:

resp_threadless[] and resp_threaded[] are global int arrays and their size is n;

```
int n = 100000;

void function() {
  for (long j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    int count = 0;
    double x = vetor[j];
      while (x > 1.0) {
      x = sqrt(x);
      ++count;
    }
   resp_threadless[j] = count;
  }
}

DWORD WINAPI function_th( LPVOID lpParam ) {
for (long j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
    int count = 0;
    double x = vetor[j];
      while (x > 1.0) {
      x = sqrt(x);
      ++count;
    }
   resp_threadless[j] = count;
  }
}
```

I benchmarked the first function by just calling her:

```
function();
```

And the second one like this:

```
HANDLE hThreadArray[1];
DWORD dwThreads[1];
hThreadArray[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, function_th, NULL , 0, &(dwThreads[0]));
WaitForMultipleObjects(1, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(hThreadArray[0]);
```

Keep in mind that I know that calling multiple threads using function_th() will not parallelize it, this is just a test because i was having really strange results, so I decided to see what would happen with one thread and one function using the SAME code.

I tested this in a Intel Atom N270, and windows XP with NUMPROC = 1.

Results:
Serial code: 1485 ms
One Thread: 425 ms

I've had similar results using multiprocessor machines, and even with code using semaphores to parallelize the work done by the threads.

Does anyone has any idea of what could be happening?

**EDIT**

Inverting the order, running multiple times each one, etc... -> No change

Higher N -> Thread one is proportionally even faster

Using QueryPerformanceCounter() -> No change

Thread Creation Overhead -> Should make the threaded even one slower, not faster

Original code: http://pastebin.com/tgmp5p1G

Comment: Maybe your current thread (in which you invoke `function()`) has low priority?

Comment: Did you run two tests sequentially in a single program execution? I suspect the data cache effect for `vetor[]` access.

Comment: 1. Have you tried to reverse the order, thread first and function after? (cache effect) 2. How did you measure the time?

Comment: I tried reversing it, same result.... =/

Comment: I'm measuring the time getting "(double)clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;" and subtracting one from the other.

Comment: It might be precision mode of floating point operation such as `sqrt`. I heard that Intel Atom has poor FPU performance. (the main thread and new user-created thread has different mode for C runtime math library?)

Comment: It's not the Atom, I'm also doing tests in other computers. 

"the main thread and new user-created thread has different mode for C runtime math library?" Looks like we have a winner! numbers really close to 1, sqrt() has diferrent behaviors in both codes, inside the thread sqrt(1,0000000000000095) = 1,0000000000000047, in the serial code sqrt(1,0000000000000095) = 1,0000000000000049. I changed my code from x = sqrt(x) to x = x/2 and now everything makes sense!

Comment: Winner? I didn't know that this was a contest. **However:** You did record the `resp_threadless` values. Thus you did know that the `while` loops were runnig a different amount of `count`s. **But:** You did not say that. **Thus:** It may have been a contest, because you knew the facts from the beginning. Good job testing for known answers! **Nevertheless:** The cache effect is clearly visible too: Reversing the order **matters**. BTW: What are the different versions of the runtime libraries for the main thread and the user thread respectively?

Comment: I think you missunderstood me, I said "winner" because it's the first one of many hypotesis that finaly explained my problem. I really didn't know the answer and I've been strugling for over four days over this problem, I have to thank you a lot for helping me with this, I have this same code in three other languages (Java, Javascript and Python) and haven't had much problem until I tried C. Yes I did record resp_thredless, but I never compared the answers from the threaded with the one from the serial code since the main purpose of this program was to check performance, and not count values.

Comment: Also sqrt giving different results for the same input deffinetly wouldn't be my first guess. In my benchmark (as you can see in the code in pastebin) I'm repeating the test 5 times for each one, and getting the mean, so at least in here I can't see "cleary" the cache effect, at least none that makes one code two, three or even four times faster than the other.

Answer (score 2):

It's a `cache hit` matter. I suspect you did the benchmark in the order you described it in your question. The function was called first and the thread was called after. When you benchmark this in more detail, you will observe the reason: Data (sqrt) is availabel in cache, thus the code will execute much faster.
**Test to proove:**

1. Run the `function()` twice or even more often before calling the thread.
   The second call to function will give the quicker result already.
2. Call the thread before the function and your result will show the opposite.
   The function will show the better result.

Reason: All of the sqrt calculation (or at least lots of them) are available in cache and don't have to be recalculated. That's a lot faster.

Comment: I've tried reversing the other, running multiple times both of them, and i've got the same results.

Comment: Well, I did use your code and did exacly that. And the results were pretty clear. **Again:** How did you do the time measurement? Can you report the times for say 5 consecutive runs of the 'function()` and the `function_th()`?

Comment: I'm actually running 5 times each function and getting the mean. 
I'm measuring the time getting "(double)clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;" and subtracting one from the other.

Comment: `clock()` does not have good resolution. In `threaded()` your timing encloses to whole thread creation. Put the timing so that the just the loop is enclosed, as you did in `threadlees()`. Only call one thread. Increase n to something higher to get less errors due things done once only. And use [QueryPerformanceCounter()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for timing purposes. Maybe there is a chance to add the results to your question above (edit).

Comment: Using QueryPerformanceCounter() -> Threaded one still much faster.
Higher n -> -> Threaded one even faster.
Enclosing the whole thread creation shouldn´t change anything, since it should make the "threaded one" even slower, also in my original benchmark I wanted to count thread creation overhead.